# How to build i386 PPA packages on a 32 bit system

Tags: ppa, 32-bit, launchpad

My PPA package won't cross build its i386 binary on a 64-bit machine. I have tried it, and there are many low level system headers missing, although it will build in a 32-bit system, I have tried it on a virtual machine. Is there any way to force Launchpad to try to build my package on a real 32-bit installation?

From the error log I get via e-mail, the package is being cross-built on a 64-bit installation.

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad doesn't directly support cross-building, although in some cases build-depending on lib32somethingorother-dev may provide a biarch version of libsomethingorother-dev.  Could you link to the failing build?